# How can I tell which process is newest?

Tags: powershell, process

I have a utility which runs a process with elevated privilges (effectively allowing us to run stuff that requires admin privilege from scripts).

I need to check this utility is working, and the way I am doing this is to open a command prompt with admin privilege, detect if it has opened (if the utility is not working, it will fail to open the command prompt) and then close the command prompt again.

I can do this fine, but I want to handle the situation where a user has already got a command prompt open, by identifying which process opened most recently.

The code I have at the moment is:

```
C:\myutility.exe cmd
$proc = Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "name='cmd.exe'" 

$isnull = ($proc -eq $null)

if (!$isnull) { #Process did not start

    $latest = $proc[$proc.Length-1]
    $owner = Invoke-CimMethod -InputObject $latest -MethodName GetOwner
    foreach ($p in $proc) {
        $command = "powershell stop-process -id " + $p.Handle
        c:\myutility.exe powershell stop-process -force -id $p.Handle 
    }
    if ($owner.User -eq "Administrator") {
        write-output $true
    } else { # User is not Admin userx`
        write-output $false
    }

} else { #Failed to start administrator cmd prompt
    write-host $false 
}
```

And I want to add something whether the process is the latest one. I wondered if using the process handle would be sufficient, but I'm not 100% that the highest handle ID is the latest process.

Is there a more reliable way to do this?

Comment: Maybe you can use the [Process.StartTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.starttime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)?

Comment: Can't see Process.StartTime in Win32_Process, but you pointed me in the right direction. Looks like I can use the CreationDate property in the same way. Thanks!

Comment: PIDs are [recycled](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110107-00/?p=11803) in Windows, so relying on PID value is prone to errors.